# Transfer variables between function A and function B

Tags: php, function, variables, arguments

I have a problem with transfer variables between two functions. I want transfer variables as an argument, but I dont know how I can do this. For example:

```
function a() {
   $a = 5;
   $b = 6;
   $c = $a + $b;
}

function b() {
   echo $c;
}
```

I need to variable `$c` from first function `a()` move to second function `b()` as an argument. Is it possible? What is the syntax? Thanks a lot for every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ab {
    var $c;
    function a() {
     $a = 5;
      $b = 6;
      $this->c = $a + $b;
    }
   function b() {
   echo $this->c;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function a() {
   $a = 5;
   $b = 6;
   $c = $a + $b;
   return $c;
}

function b($c) {
   echo $c;
}

//get result from function a()
$varFromFunctionA = a();

//pass it to function b()
b($varFromFunctionA);
```

Comment: your variable naming is likely to confuse OP; better not use `$c` for each referral, e.g. use `b($b_input)`, ...

Comment: @xtofl Point taken. Rewrote it to make it a little more obvious.